# when i use typeid in template function cause error

Tags: c++11

here is code snippet i try to compile, which result to compile error:
convert const char * to int is invalid;

can anyone help debug this code ?
thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;
int sums() { return 0; }

template <typename Type, typename... T>
int sums(const Type s, const T... args)
{
    int res = 0;
    if (typeid(s) == typeid(int))
    {
        res += s;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "not int" << s << endl;
    }
    res += sums(args...);
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    cout << sums(1,"sir", 4) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A normal if does not work there, because it is evaluates at runtime, so the compiler will altough have to generate the code for res+=s, even if the if would never be true on runtime. To fix this you could use if constexpr (since C++17) or you could replace the if with funktion overloading, to distuinguish between types at runtime.

Comment: thank you for your help. i use constexpr fix it. -> constexpr (std::is_integral<T>::value)

Answer (score 0):

You try to do different things for different types, but a normal if in combination with typeid is evaluated at runtime. That mean that the compiler must generate code for both cases, because the evaluation which is executed is not clear at compiler time.

To fix this problem you must bring the decision from runtime to compile time.

Thats what `if constexpr` is for. It is evaluated at compile time and there you can write code in one branch that would not compile if the condition is not fulfilled